# Select rows with min value based on fourth column and group by first column in linux

Tags: linux

Can you please tell me how to Select rows with min value based on fourth column and group by first column in linux?

Original file

```
x,y,z,w
1,a,b,0.22
1,a,b,0.35
1,a,b,0.45
2,c,d,0.06
2,c,d,0.20
2,c,d,0.46
3,e,f,0.002
3,e,f,0.98
3,e,f,1.0
```

The file I want is as below.

```
x,y,z,w
1,a,b,0.22
2,c,d,0.06
3,e,f,0.002
```

I tried as below but this does not work.

```
sort -k1,4 -u original_file.txt | awk '!a[$1] {a[$1] = $4} $4 == a[$1]' >> out.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just sort by column 4. You need to store the entire line in the array, not just `$4`. And then print the entire array at the end.

To keep the heading from getting mixed in, I print that separately and then process the rest of the file.

```
head -n 1 original_file
tail -n +2 original_file | sort -t, -k 4n -u | awk -F, '
    !a[$1] { a[$1] = $0 } 
    END { for (k in a) print a[k] }' | sort -t, -k 1,1n >> out
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. But the output file shows only the header of the original file... Do you have any ideas??

Comment: Sorry I just updated my post, and it is comma separated. Maybe was it the reason that your edited command still does not work. Thank you for your help!!

Comment: All you have to do is add the appropriate delimiter options to the `sort` and `awk` commands. I've updated the answer.

Comment: sorry i noticed that the output file does not list all the rows. It should be a third of the original file, but the number is so much lower. If the two files are comma-delimited text file, what to be added? By the way, total number of rows are 21000000, so it should be 7000000.